# I have AND operator in Where statement of query, how can i know which statement did not returned

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a php code
SQL QUERY GOES LIKE

where and are the variable user will enter in the form.
i have a database where there are certain values for gpm and certain values for ewt
For ex as value ranging from 1-5 with difference of 0.5 eg: 1,1.5,2,2.5 etc
and ewt has values ranging from 30-100 with differerence of 10 eg: 30,40,50

so if users enters nd  it returns me values from databse
but if user enters gp and ewt as it returns me not found
How can i know that database did'nt found gpm and it found ewt

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run two queries, the current one and one with OR. Then compare the two results

Comment: Unrelated: Use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into SQL, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @aynber qould you be able to provide an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use prepared statements, see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Use `OR` instead of `AND`, and test which was matched in the `SELECT` list.

```
$command = "SELECT *, gpm = :uniluxGpm AS gpm_found, ewt = :uniluxEwt AS ewt_found from {$uniluxModel} where gpm = :uniluxGpm OR ewt = :uniluxEwt";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($command);
$stmt->execute([':uniluxGpm' => $uniluxGpm, ':uniluxEwt' => $uniluxEwt]);
```

Comment: instead of ? should i use my variable names? also what does  iiii means?

Comment: See my earlier comment about using a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: `iiii` means that the parameters are integers. If they were strings you would use `ssss`.

Comment: it shows this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\result.php:81 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\result.php on line 81        line 81 is   $stmt->bind_param("dddd", $uniluxGpm, $uniluxEwt, $uniluxGpm, $uniluxEwt);

Comment: Most posters use mysqli rather than PDO, so that's what I assumed. I'll translate ot PDO.

Comment: how can i echo gpmfound and ewtfound please help?

Comment: `if ($row['gpm_found'] == 1) { echo "GPM Found"; }`

Comment: if ($row['gpm_found'] == 1 AND $row['ewt_found'] == 1 ) {
      echo "both found";
    }

  elseif ($row['gpm_found'] == 1) {
     echo "GPM Found";
    }



  elseif ($row['ewt_found'] == 1) {
    echo "EWT FOUND";
  }

This is what i have entered and it shows correctly for both elseif statement but when i enter both gpm and ewt correctly it does shows both found

Comment: Or Statement does not work, it only returns one value even if both values are present.

Comment: Of course. Either a row matches the conditions or it doesn't. If you want separate results for each condition, use separate queries with `UNION`.

Comment: What i want is, i want to know what value is not returned so that  i can use interpolation and find value for that as well, for example if gpm is present and ewt is not present i only need to interpolate values for ewt, similarly is ewt is present and gpm is not present i only need to interpolate values for gpm and if both are not present i need to interpolate values for both. Can you please help for this?

Comment: That's what the `gpm_found` and `ewt_found` columns do.

Comment: That's for OR, is there any other way than OR because it doesn't show both both the value.

Comment: You could do three differen queries: One with `gpm = X AND ewt != Y`, a second with `gpm != X and ewt = Y`, and third with `gpm = X AND ewt = Y`.